How to apply multiple coupons in Magento 2.4.7
As per magento 2.4.7 multiple coupon codes feature available for REST Api, GraphQL.
If we want to make it work for storefont, how can we achieve this?
Thank you.

The multiple coupons per order feature is currently not available in Storefront. This feature is available only in Admin, GraphQL, and the REST API. Additionally, this is an exclusive feature in Adobe Commerce, not Magento Open Source.
Just to clarify, the multiple coupons per order feature was incorrectly listed in the release notes for Magento Open Source 2.4.7
You can refer to the Sales Configuration documentation for reference purposes.

HI @Tu Van, Thanks for your inputs, however am aware of this. if we want to achive this in the storefront, how we can do that, can you help me here.

Hey @Mani, I haven't worked with this customization, but I believe you can review the Magento_MulticouponUi to understand how it works in the Admin and then apply it to the Storefront.
